# Application that zooms to a specific part of the desktop

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opengl, desktop

I want (primarily for didactic purposes) to create a linux application which should allow the user to select a rectangle on the screen (whatever window lies within that region) and zoom it on the screen.

Where should I start? I already did something similar on windows using C# (basically I took a snapshot of the region and zoomed it with the Image control) but on linux I don't know where to start.

I was thinking about using QT for the main window, maybe openGL with Qt but I need information whether this approach may be right and some start-up tip to get started. Is using QT and openGL a good way to do this? What api/functionality should I use to draw on the screen and copy a specific region of it (and zooming it) ?

Comment: What did you use under windows?

Comment: what do you mean? I wrote I used C# and took a snapshot of the region I wanted (CopyFromScreen)

Comment: When you say you took a snapshot, you mean you hit print screen and pasted it into an image control which enlarges the image? Or there's some windows API calls you're making? Basically I was wondering if there's any reason you can't do the same thing on Linux as you do under Windows using mono... ?

Comment: FYI, there are already screen magnifier apps out there for Linux: http://magnifier.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think going with Qt is a good idea.
Perhaps a good start could be the Qt [screenshot example](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/desktop-screenshot.html). Then creating a simple QApplication to display the zoomed part according to the mouse position should be way feasible, even for a first Qt project !

I really recommend you to use QtCreator to develop on linux it's a really great IDE.

Comment: I did it, and with QT it was a piece of cake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) to port your c# code to Linux? There's [quite a few options for GUI toolkits](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) and you may be able to reuse some code from your Windows app.

Comment: It uses windows-specific functions and as I wrote I want to do this natively in linux, I don't want to use Java but just plain C/C++